# How to find socket's ip C# BeginReceive

Tags: c#, sockets

I Listen to specific port with `BeginReceive()` method.
How I can find sender's IP?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should elaborate your questions with more details.

Anyway you can find a complete example on how to use `BeginReceive()` and the other asynchronous methods of the `Socket` class in a clear and detailed ["Asynchronous Server Socket Example" MSDN Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx).

The trick as you will read, is to initialize a custom state object (where you can put the opened Socket information) when you accept the connection and you are going to call `BeginReceive`, so that the receive callback will be able to retrieve that state with `IAsyncResult.AsyncResult` property.

Following the linked example, you can retrieve the "sender" (remote) ip address this way (in AcceptCallback, ReadCallback, where handler is an istance of the `Socket` class):

```
IPAddress remoteAddress = ((IPEndPoint)handler.RemoteEndPoint).Address;
```